# Bootstrap col-xs-6 still stacking instead of showing 2 png images side by side

Tags: grid

I have 6 png images and they look fine when viewed at col-lg-2 and col-sm-4 but at col-xs-6, it only shows 1 image per row with all images stacked.

Thank you for your time!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <div class="mt-5 mx-auto">
          <img src="img/python.png" height="75px" width="75px">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
          <div class="mt-5 mx-auto">
            <img src="img/ruby.png" height="75px" width="73px">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <div class="mt-5 mx-auto">
            <img src="img/javascript.png" height="70px" width="70px">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <div class="mt-5 mx-auto">
            <img src="img/html.png" height="75px" width="85px">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <div class="mt-5 mx-auto">
            <img src="img/css.png" height="75px" width="62px">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <div class="mt-5 mx-auto">
            <img src="img/angular.png" height="75px" width="70px">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row flex-nowrap">

If not then

<div class="container flex-nowrap">
```

The use of "flex-nowrap" works for me, it forces the containers to stay in line

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried adding flex-nowrap. Now all 6 images stay in line so when I shrink the screen the other images are off-screen.

Comment: You will need to shrink the images, not sure if bootstrap has anything to help with this ...